# anaconda env: cupti64_100.dll not found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conv-neural-network

```
        # output metadata end of epochs
        print('\nAdding run metadata for epoch ' + str(batch_idx) + '\n')
        run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
        run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
        summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step],
                              feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.0},  # test_xs, test,_ys
                              options=run_options,
                              run_metadata=run_metadata)
        train_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%03d' % batch_idx)
        train_writer.add_summary(summary, batch_idx)
```

2019-11-10 16:07:00.007157: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:174] Profiler session started.

2019-11-10 16:07:00.012641: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'cupti64_100.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_100.dll not found

2019-11-10 16:07:00.018396: W tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:182] Encountered error while starting profiler: Unavailable: CUPTI error: CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.

2019-11-10 16:07:00.108662: I tensorflow/core/platform/default/device_tracer.cc:641] Collecting 0 kernel records, 0 memcpy records.

2019-11-10 16:07:00.114275: E tensorflow/core/platform/default/device_tracer.cc:68] CUPTI error: CUPTI could not be loaded or symbol could not be found.

W1110 16:07:00.226252 11440 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From training.py:284: The name tf.train.Saver is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Saver instead.

my setup:
-Python 3.7.3
-cudatoolkit 10.0.130
-cudnn 7.6.0
-tensorflow 1.14.0
-tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0

**i using Anaconda environment.**
please help me what should i do?

Comment: **i just installed nvidia cuda 10.0.130 and copy cudnn 7.6.0 to C:\Program Files and it worked. please close this post.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

Installed `nvidia cuda 10.0.130` and copy `cudnn 7.6.0` to `C:\Program Files` has resolved the issue.